# Why are conservative vector fields the gradient of some potential function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Today I was introduced to conservative vector fields, and we were given a definition for this class of vector fields.

So a vector field is conservative if there exists a potential function for which the vector field is equal to the gradient of the potential function. But why is this the case, why was it defined in this way? And how come that this leads to consequences such that integrating along a curve in a conservative vector field only depends on the start and end points.

I hope I made myself clear enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Line Integrals: For any (piecewise-smooth) curve $C$ going from $A$ to $B$, we have
$$\int_C \overrightarrow{\nabla f}\cdot d\vec r = f(B)-f(A).$$
The derivation is in every calculus book.

Here is why such fields are called conservative. Given a vector field $\vec F$, if $\vec F = \overrightarrow{\nabla f}$, then physicists call $-f$ the potential energy and total energy — kinetic plus potential — is conserved. We see this as follows: Parametrize $C$ by $\vec r(t)$, $a\le t\le b$. By Newton's second law, $\vec F = m\vec a = m\frac{d\vec v}{dt}$, so
$$\int_C \vec F\cdot d\vec r = \int_a^b m\frac{d\vec v}{dt}\cdot\frac{d\vec r}{dt}dt =\int_a^b m\frac{d\vec v}{dt}\cdot\vec v \,dt = \frac12 m\|\vec v\|^2\Big|_A^B = \Delta KE.$$
Combining this with the result above, we have $\Delta f = \Delta KE$, so, remembering that $PE = -f$, we see that
$$\Delta KE + \Delta PE = 0.$$
That is, total energy $KE + PE$ is conserved along any path.